# Почему не работает has_one through между моделями в разных базах?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

rails, postgres, devise. Есть сторонняя база с таблицей Corporations, к ней я подключился успешно. Цель: создать модель User, которая будет привязана к corporation, чтобы дать возможность корпорации авторизоваться как юзеру. Решил сделать отношение через has_one through.

user_corporation.rb:

```
class UserCorporation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :corporation
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable,
            :rememberable,
            :trackable,
            :timeoutable,
            :authentication_keys => [:login]

    has_one :user_corporation
    has_one :corporation, :through => :user_corporation
end
```

corporation.rb:

```
class Corporation < OtherBaseconfiguration
    self.table_name = 'Corporations'
    has_one :user_corporation
    has_one :user, :through => :user_corporation
end
```

миграция:

```
class CreateUserCorporations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_corporations do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :corporation, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`rake db:migrate` выполнил, таблица создалась. В консоли пробую получить corporate у пользователя, получаю ошибку:

```
irb(main):006:0> @corpor.corporation
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ОШИБКА:  отношение "user_corporations" не существует
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"user_corporations"'::reg...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"user_corporations"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:733:in `column_definitions'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:186:in `columns'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:49:in `columns_hash'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:85:in `column_for'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:94:in `bind'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:103:in `last_chain_scope'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:139:in `add_constraints'
... 13 levels...
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/marson/rails_project/infinity/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/marson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

что я делаю не так? по такому же подобию сделал связь users_roles - все работает прекрасно(единственное отличие, там `role has_many:users_roles`)

Comment: Чудес не бывает. В `rails db` содержимое этой таблицы запрашивается? Просто SQLем.

Comment: @D-side не совсем понял, что за rails db? это файл?

Comment: разновидность консоли, напрямую в БД.

Comment: @D-side, `app_development=> select * from user_corporations
app_development-> ;
 id | user_id | corporation_id | created_at | updated_at 
----+---------+----------------+------------+------------
(0 строк)`

Comment: То есть, в этой же базе эта таблица есть. Тогда у меня нет вариантов, у меня не воспроизводится.

Comment: @D-side, не совсем. _Есть сторонняя база с таблицей Corporations, к ней я подключился успешно._ User и Corporation в разных таблицах

Comment: Сторонняя или нет, неважно. Если миграции на ней запускались, то таблица должна там быть.

Comment: А каким образом добавлена сторонняя база? Через `database.yml`?
Возможно стоит в модели `UserCorporation` указать соединение (`establish_connection`)

Comment: @anoam, да. `other_baseconfiguration:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: Configuration
  username: test
  password: test`. other_baseconfiguration.rb: `class OtherBaseconfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :other_baseconfiguration
  self.abstract_class = true
end`. corporation.rb: `class Corporation < OtherBaseconfiguration
  self.table_name = 'Corporations'
 has_one :user_corporation, class_name: "UserCorporation", foreign_key: "corporation_id"
 has_one :user, :through => :user_corporation`

Comment: причем если просто запросить первую запись в user_corporation, то ошибки нет: `irb(main):001:0> @rr = UserCorporation.first
  UserCorporation Load (24.4ms)  SELECT  "user_corporations".* FROM "user_corporations"  ORDER BY "user_corporations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
`

Comment: Так-так, погодите. Какая модель в какой базе?

Comment: @D-side, Corporation в Configuration(other_baseconfiguration в database.yml), User и UserCOrporation в app_development

Comment: А, ну да. Он пытается с`join`ить `Corporations`->`UsersCorporations(where user_id = X)` и взять `first` у результата. Это должно падать, они ж в разных базах :)

Comment: именно. http://emphaticsolutions.com/2009/11/23/has_many_through_across_databases.html если я правильно понял автора статьи - то так склеить модели из разных баз можно

Comment: `JOIN`'ить SQL'ем -- нет, нельзя. Его гем [**довольно твердолобый**](https://github.com/briandoll/st-elsewhere/blob/master/lib/st-elsewhere.rb#L66), если я правильно понимаю исходники; там должна быть проблема N+1 запроса (он просто делает through напролом, обходя каждый объект). Похоже, что тут проще всего вручную жонглировать `id`шниками. Почешу репу, как это лучше завернуть.

Comment: Во-оу, этот гем 2009 года и только ожидает выхода Rails 3. Нет, вы вряд ли им воспользуетесь :D

Comment: ну тогда остается только добавить столбец corporate_id к User, и не мучить далее

Comment: @M.V в модель `UserCorporation` явно пропиши `establish_connection Rails.env` и попробуй выполнить то же самое.